# can't define a secret to pull from vault as a variable

Tags: gitlab, jwt, hashicorp-vault, vault

I have vault configured and working.
I also have on-premise gitlab server that integrating with vault.
They're working perfectly together.
The problem starts when I try to call a secret with a parameter like so:

```
    SECRET:
        vault: $path_secret@kv-secret
variables:
    path_secret: path/to/secret
```

it is working if I set it without the "/" like so:

```
    SECRET:
        vault: $first/$second/$third@kv-secret
variables:
    first: path
    second: to
    third: secret
```

please ignore any syntax issue. the problem is with the logic not with the syntax.
it seems like there is a problem specifing "/" in a variables for vault secrets.

Also, I found that if I set the policy responsible to read this “path/to/secret” to be:

```
path "*" {
      capabilities = ["read","list"]
}
```

it is working with no problem at all!
My vault work perfectly on any other case with my gitlab ci.

I tried escaping the "/" character with "//" and "\" as well as surround the variable with quotes on createtion and upon use but still no luck.

Update: Just found out that we have upgrade to a newer gitlab version lately  and I fear it has something to do with this malfunctioning, we previously had version 15.10 not a big leap, but I'm not sure what could cause it

Vault version 1.12.1
Gitlab version 15.11

Comment: Can you try using your variable (with slashes) in a simple `echo` type script (like [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#define-a-cicd-variable-in-the-gitlab-ciyml-file)) in your job? Then see if something unexpected is happening to its value.

Comment: I didn't mention that I did try it. updating

Comment: Can you show the script and its output?